# Does the binomial random graph model $G(n, (\ln n)/n^2)$ obey zero-one law?

Tags: probability-theory, random-graphs

I want to know if the bionomial random graph model $G\left(n, \frac{\ln n}{n^2}\right)$ obeys Zero-one law or not?

I know that $\frac{\ln n}{n}$ is a threshold function for connectivity and for $\frac{\ln n}{n}$ zero-one law doesn't hold but what's about $\frac{\ln n}{n^2}$?

Answer (score 1):

When $p = \ln  n /n^2$, there are approximately ${n \choose 2}p(n) \approx \ln n$ edges in the graph. 
Now consider one vertex that is the extremity of an edge. What is the probability that it is connected to a second vertex?
There are $n-2$ other vertices, so it gives an expectation of $\ln  n /n \rightarrow 0$ neighbours.
In short,  all edges are isolated. The theory of the limit graph just describes an infinity of isolated edges and isolated vertices, so there is a zero-one law, albeit fairly trivial.